# Ink Message must not be generic Warning

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, ink, smart-contract

on writing `to: &mut AccountId`, it throws warning to use explicit lifetime name needed here.

[image]

```
    #[ink(message)] 
    pub fn delegate(&mut self, to: &mut AccountId) {
        let caller = self.env().caller();
        let voters = self.voters.get(caller).unwrap_or_default();
        let voters_to = self.voters.get(*to).unwrap_or_default();
        assert!(!voters.voted, "You already voted.");

        assert!(*to != caller, "Self-delegation is disallowed");

        while voters_to.delegate != [0; 32].into() {
            *to = voters_to.delegate;
        }
    }
```

including lifetime, but it throws ink message must not be generic. I remove `#[ink(message)]` and it works fine and `#[inline]` as well

[image]

```
    #[ink(message)] 
    pub fn delegate<'a>(&mut self, to: &'a mut AccountId) {
        let caller = self.env().caller();
        let voters = self.voters.get(caller).unwrap_or_default();
        let voters_to = self.voters.get(*to).unwrap_or_default();
        assert!(!voters.voted, "You already voted.");

        assert!(*to != caller, "Self-delegation is disallowed");

        while voters_to.delegate != [0; 32].into() {
            *to = voters_to.delegate;
        }
    }
```

Anybody explain me why this is happening? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `to: &'a mut AccountId` to `to: AccountId`, and just use the `AccountId` directly in your ink! message.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use references in `[ink(message)]`.

I think you want this function to be public, so it needs to be `[ink(message)]`. You can just simply remove the reference of the parameter and work with its value.

Comment: should I omit `#[ink(message)]` then?

Comment: I updated my answer)

Comment: thanks for help I need to define `pub fn delegate(&mut self, to: AccountId)` to as `mut`, I have only found to use `&mut` as  `pub fn delegate(&mut self, to: &mut AccountId)` but #[ink(message)] doesn't use references.

Comment: the `&mut self` or `&self` part is necessary for a message.  `mut self` means that the message will mutate the contract storage, while `self` is only a view function